# web3 error - web3.eth.Contract is not a constructor

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript

i try to get the contract balance and im using this

```
var Web3 = require('web3')
var web3 = new Web3('ropsten.infura.io/v3/123456789')
var abi = abi is here ;

var contractAddress = '0x31111.....';
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);
//var address = '0x31111......';

web3.eth.getBalance(contract.address, function (e, r) {
   $('contractBalanceAgi').text(convertWeiToEth(r).toFixed(4))
 })
```

and when running this i get following error in my console
 web3.eth.Contract is not a constructor

when i googled for it some said its because of the new web3 js version
but the new web3 version requires this
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress)
new and capital C

Comment: can you try `console.log("Web3 version", web3.version);`?  I have a hunch you are running a different Web3 version than you think.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the cause of your issue but I am fairly sure that you need to include the protocol prefix in the URL provided to the web3 constructor:

```
var web3 = new Web3('ropsten.infura.io/v3/123456789')
```

Should include the protocol:

```
var web3 = new Web3('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/123456789')
```

(P.S. please don't use var, const is fairly appropriate)

Comment: didnt work mate

Comment: updated my answer @yappytwan, please let me know if that sorts it out :)

Comment: no is not working and additional i get this error now Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAccounts' of undefined

Comment: That seems like progress to me @yappytwan, please share the code making use of "getAccounts".

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: this.provider.sendAsync is not a function
    at s.sendAsync (web3.js:1)
    at r.e [as getAccounts] (web3.js:1)
    at (index):70

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: web3.eth.Contract is not a constructor
    at exchange.js:6

Comment: You should assign a provider instead of passing the url directly. Such as: 
`const provider = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss://ropsten.infura.io/v3/1234543');
const web3 = new Web3(provider);`